# how to find max value in 6 columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this.

```
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| studentCode | term1 | term2 | term3 | term4 | term6 |
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I want to return the max value of terms in each rows.

like this:

```
SELECT studentCode, maxterm FROM my_tbl
```

how can I fill maxterm with my max value.
thanks...

Comment: Is it a view table? If not you should consider changing the table structure,something like   students (id,name,code) grades(student_id,grade,term)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT studentCode, GREATEST(term1, term2, term3, term4, ... ) FROM my_tbl
```

[Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest)

Answer (score 1):

Use [GREATEST()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest)

```
select studentCode,
       greatest(term1, term2, term3, term4, term5, term6)
from my_tbl;
```

Answer (score 0):

for only a few columns, you could use an if-clause.

```
SELECT IF(`col_1` > `col_2`, `col_1`, `col_2`) AS max FROM `my_table`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using GREATEST:

```
SELECT studentCode, GREATEST( term1, term2, term3, term4, term5, term6 )
FROM my_tbl
```